# CreateFileMapping cause crashed for network file lost

Tags: c++, winapi

I use `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile` APIs to read a large file from network. During reading, the network is lost and my program crashed with 'page error', because the file mapping view no longer exists. How can I handle this situation, to allow the program to deal with network lost without crash?

Comment: Use SEH (structured exception handling) as mentioned in this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/reading-and-writing-from-a-file-view to handle such exceptions

Comment: *file mapping no longer exist* this is not true. Must not be crash

Comment: I use
__try
  {
    if (mBuffer && &mBuffer(mBegin)) // mBuffer is return value of MapViewOfFile API and mBegin indicate the position to read 
    { ...// read mBuffer from mBegin position }
  }
  __except(GetExceptionCode()==EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR ?
    EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER : EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH)
  {
    ...//error handle
  }
when reading,  and it doesn't crash this time. Is this enougn of  SEH (structured exception handling) ?

Comment: As long as all read operations are guarded with a `__try`/`__except` handler it is sufficient. You would probably want to report the failure from the `__except` filter to callers. Make sure you understand the implications when [mixing SEH and C++ exception handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/mixing-c-structured-and-cpp-exceptions).

Comment: Got it! Thank you all very much~